# how to open a csv in universal new line mode through django upload?

Tags: python, django, csv, django-forms

I am trying to upload a csv file in a django form:

```
class CSVUploadForm(forms.Form):
    csv_file = forms.FileField(label='Select a CSV file to import:',)

    def clean(self):
        file_csv = self.cleaned_data['csv_file']
        records = csv.reader(open('/mypath/'+file_csv.name, 'rU'), dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```

I need to open the file in universal new line mode.  I can do that with "open" method above, but that will not work for this form because the file I am dealing with is an in memory uploaded version of the csv.

**How do I pass the universal new line mode flag rU to something like this**:

```
records = csv.reader(file_csv, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `str.splitlines()` -- which automatically splits on universale line-breaks -- in the following manner:

```
def clean(self):
    file_csv = self.cleaned_data['csv_file']
    lines = file_csv.read().splitlines()
    records = csv.reader(lines, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```

If you are worried about the memory cost of creating the `lines` variable, you can force Django to save the file to a local file on disk changing the `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` variable in settings.py ([more on this variable here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#where-uploaded-data-is-stored)):

```
# add to your settings.py
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 0
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = '/tmp'
```

Then to process the file from it's tmp folder using universal mode:

```
def clean(self):
    file_csv = open(self.cleaned_data['csv_file'].temporary_file_path, 'rU')
    records = csv.reader(file_csv, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem with the solution above is that it reads the whole file all at once, make it not acceptable when processing large csv file. For small CSV files files will be saved to disk instead of being kept in memory which is also not so great.

I've created a class to handle new lines

```
class FileWithUniversalNewLine(object):

    def __init__(self, file_obj):
        self.file = file_obj

    def lines(self):
        buff = ""  # In case of reading incomplete line, buff will temporarly keep the incomplete line
        while True:
            line = self.file.read(2048)
            if not line:
                if buff:
                    yield buff
                raise StopIteration

            # Convert all new lines into linux new line
            line = buff + line.replace("\r\n", "\n").replace("\r", "\n")
            lines = line.split("\n")
            buff = lines.pop()
            for sline in lines:
                yield sline

    def close(self):
        self.file.close()

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.file.__exit__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.lines()
```

Usage:

```
csvfile = FileWithUniversalNewLine(file_csv)
records = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```